# Inferencing in Protege does not infer types based on `subClassOf`

Tags: type-inference, ontology, rdfs

We are developing an ontology, where we need to infer the type of each node, based on some mappings defined in `# Test mapping file` section. We tried `rdfs:subClassOf`, as in the below snippet, but it doesn't infer types. Ideally we want to infer `Person 1` and `Person 2` to `NodeTypePerson`, also `sydney` and `canberra` to `NodeTypeCity`.

I tried `owl:equivalentClass` instead but no luck. `rdfs:range`  and `rdfs:domain` infer types as expected, but having trouble inferring with `rdfs:subClassOf`. Any advice is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

`owl:equivalentClass` works in Protege. (If infers the type). But can't we use `rdfs:subClassOf` similarly? Actually I want a way to get this done with RDFS inferencing, where `owl:equivalentClass` doesn't work obviously. Is there any other RDFS property we can use here?

````
# baseURI: http://www.Test-app.com/ns
@prefix :          <http://www.Test-app.com/ns#> .

@prefix rdf:       <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:      <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:       <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix acl:       <http://www.w3.org/ns/auth/acl#> .
@prefix cc:        <http://creativecommons.org/ns#> .
@prefix cert:      <http://www.w3.org/ns/auth/cert#> .
@prefix csvw:      <http://www.w3.org/ns/csvw#> .
@prefix dc:        <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix dcam:      <http://purl.org/dc/dcam/> .
@prefix dcat:      <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#> .
@prefix dctype:    <http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/> .
@prefix foaf:      <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix ldp:       <http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#> .
@prefix posixstat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/posix/stat#> .
@prefix schema:    <https://schema.org/> .
@prefix shacl:     <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix skos:      <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix skosxl:    <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#> .
@prefix solid:     <http://www.w3.org/ns/solid/terms#> .
@prefix swapdoc:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/doc#> .
@prefix ui:        <http://www.w3.org/ns/ui#> .
@prefix vann:      <http://purl.org/vocab/vann/> .
@prefix vcard:     <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> .
@prefix vs:        <http://www.w3.org/2003/06/sw-vocab-status/ns#> .
@prefix ws:        <http://www.w3.org/ns/pim/space#> .

@base <http://www.Test-app.com/ns> .

<http://www.Test-app.com/ns>
    rdf:type       owl:Ontology ;
    dc:title       "Test Ontology"@en ; 
    owl:versionIRI <http://www.Test-app.com/ns/0.1> .

# Test mapping file

@prefix test:  <http://www.Test-app.com/ns#> .

    
:Person
    a               rdfs:Class ;
    owl:equivalentClass :NodeTypePerson .

:locatedNear
    a               rdf:Property ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :NodeCustomAttribute ;    
    rdfs:label      "Located Near" .

:Location
    a            rdfs:Class ;
    rdfs:label   "Location" ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :NodeTypeCity ;
    rdfs:comment "This represents a geolocation." .

:City
    a               rdfs:Class ;
    rdfs:label      "City" ;
    rdfs:comment    "This represents a city." ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :Location .


# Some graph instances data

:sydney
    a            :City ;
    rdfs:label   "Sydney" ;
    rdfs:comment "Australia's largest city." .

:canberra
    a            :City ;
    rdfs:label   "Canberra" ;
    rdfs:comment "Australia's national capital." .


:person1
    a            :Person ;
    rdfs:label   "Person 1" ;
    rdfs:comment "First vertex." ; 
    :locatedNear :sydney .

:person2
    a            :Person ;
    rdfs:label   "Person 2" ;
    rdfs:comment "Second vertex." ;
    :locatedNear :canberra .

# Types
:NodeTypePerson
    rdf:type         rdfs:Class ;   
    rdfs:label       "NodeTypePerson" ;
    rdfs:comment     "" ;   
    vs:term_status   "stable" ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://www.Test-app.com/ns> .

:NodeTypeCity
    rdf:type         rdfs:Class ;   
    rdfs:label       "NodeTypeCity" ;
    rdfs:comment     "" ;   
    vs:term_status   "stable" ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://www.Test-app.com/ns> .```
````

Comment: as every URI in Semantic Web, it's case sensitive: it should be `owl:equivalentClass` - don't write it by hand if you're using Protege anyways ...

Comment: Also, I do not agree with your modelling - at least it sounds weird to say that each person is a personnodetype - but if it's sufficient for you, it's ok.

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser. Now `owl:equivalentClass` works in Protege. (If infers the type). But can't we use  `rdfs:subClassOf` similarly? Actually I want a way to get this done with RDFS inferencing, where `owl:equivalentClass` doesn't work obviously. What other RDFS property can we use here?

Comment: `rdfs:subClassOf` works as well - why should it not work? If you say :Person rdfs:subClassOf :NodeTypePerson`, then any instance of `:Person` will be an instance of `:NodeTypePerson` as well

Comment: rdfs:subClassOf should work. Which reasoner are you using with Protege?

Comment: It uses `HermiT 1.4.3.456`. In Protege, I can see the class hierarchy, but the new type does not populate in the `Types` section, whereas it does with `owl:equivalentClass`.